# XAML Storyboarding - Setting a bool to "False" in a storyboard locks it as false

Tags: wpf, xaml

this is a somewhat odd one.
I'm looking to use XAML to get an expander *(or anything with checked and unchecked states such as a Togglebutton and the like)* to set itself back to being collapsed/unchecked after being 'ignored' (for lack of a better term) after a given period of time.

*Currently* the parameters I'm using to decide if it's being 'ignored' are that 
**MouseOver=False** and **IsExpanded=True**, when this trigger is raised, it'll begin a storyboard that, after about 3 seconds will set "IsExpanded" to "False".

Which is working just fine.

The problem is when you then want to RE-expand the expander - you can't, because the storyboard appears to be **holding** it as False.

I'm probably just doing something dumb/not considering some angle of this, but it's incredibly frustrating.
If it should turn out that it can't be done with XAML alone then that's okay, but i would prefer a purely XAML solution *if* one exists.

To better illustrate the issue, i've made a sample project you can look at that can be downloaded     [Here.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/w0tj944jejs8u6v/SelfUnchecking%20Example.rar?dl=0)

Alternatively, here's the code to view:

```
<Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="ExpanderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
            <Style.Resources>
                <Storyboard x:Key="ExpanderSelfCollapseStoryboard">
                    <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="{x:Null}" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Expander.IsExpanded)">
                        <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3" Value="False" />
                    </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Tag)" Storyboard.TargetName="{x:Null}">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Not long..."/>
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3" Value="Notice you can't open the expander anymore :("/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </Style.Resources>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard x:Name="ExpanderSelfCollapseStoryboard_BeginStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource ExpanderSelfCollapseStoryboard}" />
                    </MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Property="IsExpanded" Value="True" />
                        <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False" />
                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                </MultiTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Expander x:Name="localExpander"
                  Background="DodgerBlue"
                  Header="Expand me!"
                  Style="{StaticResource ExpanderStyle}"
                  Tag="Up there!">
            <Border Height="200"
                    Margin="5"
                    Background="Orange">
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                           FontSize="20"
                           FontWeight="Bold"
                           Foreground="White"
                           Text="Now move your mouse over the whitespace for a few seconds please."
                           TextAlignment="Center"
                           TextWrapping="Wrap" />
            </Border>
        </Expander>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   FontSize="22"
                   Foreground="LightGray"
                   Text="{Binding ElementName=localExpander,
                                  Path=Tag}"
                   TextAlignment="Center" />
    </Grid>
```

I'd be thankful for any help or advice anyone can render.

Thanks,

-- Logan

Comment: It would be better if you could place the relevant code inside the question. External links have a habit of rotting.